# Android app not supported on any device?

Tags: java, android

I made an app which was working fine. I am not sure what caused my app to not support on any devices after it is published in the play store.

Here is my gradle file.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "############"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 12
        versionName "12"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

The only change I added onto one of my classes is this.

```
   if (Build.VERSION_CODES.N <= android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT) {
                    // FileProvider required for Android 7.  Sending a file URI throws exception.
                    photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                            BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
                            photoFile);

                } else {
                    // For older devices:
                    // Samsung Galaxy Tab 7" 2 (Samsung GT-P3113 Android 4.2.2, API 17)
                    // Samsung S3
                    photoURI = Uri.fromFile(photoFile);
                }
```

That was a code I got to check what the current build version is. Does this help?

How can i make it available to back to all devices as it was before ?

Comment: I this wrong condition write this way (Build.VERSION_CODES.N >= android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT)

Comment: @PravinFofariya its not that. If i do that, the camera crashes.

Comment: Can you post the manifest xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me the issue was this line in the manifest file:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" android:required="true" />
```

The correct way to do it is like this - where the required is set to false

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" android:required="false" />
```